# PermissionError with pip3

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, python-3.x, pip

This is the error when I try to get anything with pip3
I'm not sure what to do

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 671, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 237, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-                        packages/Django-1.7.2.dist-info'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/omega/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: `pip3 install package_name --user` will install the package only for current user, thereby preventing any permission error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use `sudo` to install globally or have permissions to write to the folder. Or as @Alasdair commented using a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) is a better option.

Comment: Avoid using `sudo` to save yourself a lot of trouble down the road. `sudo` will install the Python packages 'globally' and may overwrite existing installation, cause dependency errors and affect other users.  Use `virtualenv` where possible, otherwise `pip install <package> --user`

Answer (score 71):

just install them using --user option which install the package only for the current user and not for all

```
pip install xxxxxx --user
```

Answer (score 6):

```
pip3 install --user <package_name>
```

No need to write your username in place of --user.